# how to upgrade visual studio to support c# desktop apps

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows 8 apps installed, now i want to upgrade it to also support c# desktop apps. 
Can you please help me out in upgrading it so that in the end I want to have only one Visual studio that supports both Windows 8 Store apps + C# desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to buy Visual Studio Professional 2013 if you want a single program to do both.

Microsoft have 3 Express versions:

- Express 2013 for Web - (does ASP.NET & ASP.NET MVC web sites)
- Express 2013 for Windows - (does Windows 8 and windows Phone apps)
- Express 2013 for Windows Desktop - does C# desktop apps (Winforms, WPF)

To do both Windows 8 Store apps and C# desktop apps you need 2 versions of express installed.

The Professional (and higher) versions however can do all these types of project in one application.

See Microsoft for details:

[Visual Studio Express versions](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx)

[Visual Studio Professional](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-professional-with-msdn-vs) NB - it can be bought with or without a MSDN subscription.

Comment: okay i understand...what if VS express for Windows 8 store apps has a solution which contains two projects a simple c# project and a windows 8 app project, can i use this kind of solution with two separate VS installation .?

Comment: I don't know. You might have to try it and find out!